# How to access a field on a ng-repeat generated table?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to AngularJS and have only been toying with it. I guess this must be an easy thing to do.

I have a 3 column table generated with ng-repeat. Each row has a button which calls a function and i want to pass an argument to it, basically a text value on the 2nd column of the specific row that whose button was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it into the function in the reapater, example:

```
$scope.numbers = [1,2,3]
$scope.myFunc = function(num) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers" ng-click="myFunc(num)">Click me! {{num}}</div>
```

Comment: Wow! So simple. gotta love angular and stackoverflow. Thanks :)